# Where can I get the raw web log file in Nexcess C panel?

Tags: webserver, apache-log-files

In Nexcess C panel where can i get the raw web log file which I can download and analyze it with offline web log analyzer tool.

In current interface I am not finding the log files.

Comment: Does this help article from the Nexcess website answer your question?  [How to view website error and access logs](https://docs.nexcess.net/article/how-to-view-website-error-and-access-logs.html)